# Custom Popup Boxes in HTML, JavaScript, and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

I am trying to create a popup box similar to this: [Click Here](http://www.bijusubhash.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/Simple-Popup-Box-using-CSS-and-jQuery.jpg)

I only want to use JavaScript. I realize I am probably making this task harder by making this requirement, but I am still trying to learn JavaScript, so I don't really want to confuse myself with JQuery. I basically want to make a prompt or alert style popup box. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: So what's your question? what have u tried?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't the place for a tutorial. Try implementing something, and if you get stuck, ask a specific question. Also, jQuery shouldn't confuse you if you're learning Javascript. It will certainly make things easier in this case, and will probably broaden your understanding.

Comment: My question is; how do I make a popup box, similar to the link I posted, with only HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Comment: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

Comment: bootstrap is not an answer.. :(

Comment: you can try jquery popup dialog, http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form..

Comment: @user2339815 Honestly, even though I have been developing since quite awhile, I feel that JavaScript should be around only minimally while displaying UI items like pop ups, which is why I authored [PopScript](http://popscript.relfor.co/). I hope it helps!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the video tutorial for custom popup
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zK4nXa84Km4

```
    <!-- html file -->
    <div id="blanket" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div id="popUpDiv" style="display:none;">

        <a href="#" onclick="popup('popUpDiv')" >Click to Close CSS Pop Up</a>
    </div>  
   <a id="link" onclick="popup('popUpDiv')">Click to Open CSS Pop Up</a>
```

--script -------------

```
function toggle(div_id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(div_id);
    if ( el.style.display == 'none' ) { el.style.display = 'block';}
    else {el.style.display = 'none';}
}
function blanket_size(popUpDivVar) {
    if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') {
        viewportheight = window.innerHeight;
    } else {
        viewportheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    }
    if ((viewportheight > document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight) && (viewportheight > document.body.parentNode.clientHeight)) {
        blanket_height = viewportheight;
    } else {
        if (document.body.parentNode.clientHeight > document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight) {
            blanket_height = document.body.parentNode.clientHeight;
        } else {
            blanket_height = document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight;
        }
    }
    var blanket = document.getElementById('blanket');
    blanket.style.height = blanket_height + 'px';
    var popUpDiv = document.getElementById(popUpDivVar);
    popUpDiv_height=blanket_height/2-200;//200 is half popup's height
    popUpDiv.style.top = popUpDiv_height + 'px';
}
function window_pos(popUpDivVar) {
    if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') {
        viewportwidth = window.innerHeight;
    } else {
        viewportwidth = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    }
    if ((viewportwidth > document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth) && (viewportwidth > document.body.parentNode.clientWidth)) {
        window_width = viewportwidth;
    } else {
        if (document.body.parentNode.clientWidth > document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth) {
            window_width = document.body.parentNode.clientWidth;
        } else {
            window_width = document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth;
        }
    }
    var popUpDiv = document.getElementById(popUpDivVar);
    window_width=window_width/2-200;//200 is half popup's width
    popUpDiv.style.left = window_width + 'px';
}
function popup(windowname) {
    blanket_size(windowname);
    window_pos(windowname);
    toggle('blanket');
    toggle(windowname);     
}
```

css

```
#blanket {
   background-color:#111;
   opacity: 0.65;
   *background:none;
   position:absolute;
   z-index: 9001;
   top:0px;
   left:0px;
   width:100%;
}

#popUpDiv {
    position:absolute;
    background:url(pop-back.jpg) no-repeat;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    border:5px solid #000;
    z-index: 9002;
}

#popUpDiv { a position:relative; top:20px; left:20px}
```

[Custom Popup Tutorial](http://webdesignandsuch.com/how-to-create-a-popup-with-css-and-javascript/)

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info)

Comment: Ok Quentin, I added code and jsFiddle. Is it against policy to answer then improve your answer like add jfFiddle and more, or is that why people vote down?

Comment: It's usually helpful to avoid submitting an answer until it is a complete answer. Nobody can tell if you plan to edit a link-only post.